# How to delete rows with selected text?

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheet1 with every other cell on column "B" has the following letteres, "LLC". My vba script should clear all "LLC" and horizontally delete entire ROW.

The code I have already used:

```
Sub deleteRowswithSelectedText()
For Each CELL In Selection
   If CELL.Value(i, 2) = "LLC" Then
      Rows(CELL.Row).ClearContents
   End If
Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? error?

Comment: @GMALC     Compile error:   Variable not defined

Comment: Are you selecting the range?

Comment: Currently I am not.

Comment: I tried something different and I remain with an error.

Comment: If you don't have a range selected then it will not work. When you say in selection you have either selected the range physically on the worksheet or used vba to select the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, If you want to loop through each cell and test it you can, but you will need to loop from the bottom to the top. Another way is to use a filter and delete all the visible rows at the same time.

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lr - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B") = "LLC" Then
            Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

Another way is to use a filter and delete every row that has "LLC" in column B

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="LLC"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

These are just examples, there are many way to accomplish this task.

The code below is probable closer to what you were trying to do.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your worksheet name
    For Each CELL In .Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        If CELL.Value = "LLC" Then
            CELL.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next CELL
End With
```

Comment: Top answer worked okay.   What I remain including to the updated TOP code is how to enter all other words, or dates that are not needed, going down and across on sheet range.   Example, I have dates with page numbers, full address per page break on the same sheet1.

Comment: @Robert-Macro, you need to ask another question with a good explanation of what you have tried, and error, with examples of before and after of what you are trying to accomplish.